# Angular 5 + Spring Boot post method doesn't work

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I use Angular 5 + Spring Boot. The problem is that I can not send information to my rest controller by post method.
I do not get any error either from the client side or from the server side.
Below the code you will see that I make get method which works correctly.
Let me apologize for my Еnglish.

Spring Entity { Dish }

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DISHES")
@Data
public class Dish implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", unique = true)
    @NotNull(message = "Ястието трябва да има име.")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 30, message = "Името на ястието трябва да е между 3 и 30 символа.")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    @NotNull(message = "Описанието на ястието не може да е празно.")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 300, message = "Описанието на ястието трябва да е между 3 и 30 символа.")
    private String description;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL ,mappedBy = "dish")
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<DishCounter> dishCounters;
}
```

Angular Entity {Dish}

```
export class Dish {

    constructor(public id?: number, public name?: string, public description?: string) {

    }
}
```

Spring Rest Controller {Dish}

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dish")
public class DishRestController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DishRestController.class);

    private final DishService dishService;

    @Autowired
    public DishRestController(final DishService dishService) {
        this.dishService = dishService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Dish>> getAllDishes() {
        logger.info("Rest controller find all dishes");
        List<Dish> dishes = dishService.getAllDishes();

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(dishes);
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> saveDish(@RequestBody Dish dish) {
        dishService.saveDish(dish);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

And Angular post Method

```
 save(dish: Dish): Observable<Dish> {
        let result: Observable<Dish>;

        result = this.http.post(this.saveDishUrl, dish)
            .map((resp => {
                console.log(resp);
                return resp;
            }))
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
                return Observable.throw(e);
            });

        console.log(result);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: It is difficult to believe there aren't any errors in either client and server side. Double check the console and network tab especially, check whether the request is sent and what the response is.

Comment: Your Angular post method looks strange. Do not return anything here. Instead ...map((resp:Response) => resp.json()) should do the trick. And remove the "return" in catch clause.

Comment: Im new in Angular. I write it like that:
 `return this.http.post(this.saveDishUrl, dish)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));`
But again nothing. I try with PostMan tool send data to my RestController  and everything passed successfully but with angular I don't have this success ... :/

Comment: Where are you calling subscribe on the post function? I don't see it here. As http post returns an observable, you must subscribe to it to make the call.

Comment: @DanR. Thanks !!! That was the problem. Post your comment to I can access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you calling subscribe on the post function? I don't see it here. As http post returns an observable, you must subscribe to it to make the call.

```
http.post(....).subscribe(response => <DO SOMETHING WITH IT>);
```

Comment: The post function or the function that call Angular Services( which calls the Api then) Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

This might not be all of the errors on your code but this is something I noticed.

Your Java `@PostMapping` doesn't specify what it should be expected to receive and what it should produce in return.

```
@PostMapping(value = "save", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

For Angular 5, you're using Angular 4 service Syntax, I thought they changed that on 5.

Comment: Thanks for the fix, but the problem is still there :/
I'm new in Angular now I write
 `return this.http.post(this.saveDishUrl, dish, {headers: this.headers})
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));`

where `headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});`
and `saveDishUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/dish/save';`

Comment: @ДжулиянОвчаров Could you use something like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to hit the REST endpoint successfully? That way we can rule out the Java issue.

Comment: For me that Angular service call looks fine, except for one thing. Does the Spring API have any security? I.E. `ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer` that require you to send `Authorization` headers with all requests?

Comment: I have not used a subscribe() to send the request now all is well thanks for the time. :)

Comment: No worries. You might wanna ask @Dan R to post his comment as answer so you can access it.